# How can I filter and sort virtual columns using Dexie.js?

Tags: reactjs, dexie

I have the need to make some `match` calculations and then sort my items in descending order by `match`.

I found the `modify` API. Is it the best tool for my needs? I get goosebumps for the object mutation... https://dexie.org/docs/Collection/Collection.modify()

I also have trouble figuring out how to let Typescript know that the new collection has one extra attribute `match`.

```js
const searchWords = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3']
query
  .filter(home => searchWords.some(word => home.comment.includes(word)))
  .modify(home => { 
    // This smells mainly for the following:
    //  - obj mutation 
    //  - typescript complains that `match` doesn't exist in Home
    home.match = searchWords.filter(word => home.comment.includes(word)).length / searchWords.length
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this isn't a Dexie-specific operation. (Dexie's `modify` function is for modifying records stored within the IndexedDB; that doesn't sound like your goal.)

Instead, [get the results array](https://dexie.org/docs/Collection/Collection.toArray()), then modify it using normal JavaScript.

```
const searchWords = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3']
const queryResults = await query
  .filter(home => searchWords.some(word => home.comment.includes(word)))
  .toArray();
const matches = queryResults
  .map(home => ({ ...home, match = searchWords.filter(word => home.comment.includes(word)).length / searchWords.length }))
  .sort((a, b) => a.match - b.match);
});
```

Comment: does that mean that the pagination and the sorting will done by js and not by Dexie, correct? that was my main concern

Comment: @FrancescoMeli - Good question. I haven't used Dexie's pagination, so I could be wrong, but I don't think it matters in your use case. From what I understand, when using Dexie, it's either (1) query operations that are directly supported by IndexedDB (in which case the browser can use its internal optimized implementation), or (2) stuff in JS that IndexedDB doesn't support, so Dexie is stuck using JS for everything. You're using a custom JS sort order, so I think you'll see little difference between Dexie JS and your own.

Comment: that's what i was making sure, thank you :)